# Embedding of half open half closed $n$-set in $n$-space

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, elementary-proofs

Let $n\geq 2$. Set $\Sigma= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: 1\leq |x|<2\}$. Assume $h:\Sigma 
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective.

***Question:*** Must $h$ also be an embedding?

Some thoughts:

1. $h|_{\operatorname{int}\Sigma}$ is an embedding.
2. $h(\operatorname{int}\Sigma)$ is open.
3. If $h$ defined on $\overline{\Sigma}$ then YES.
4. If $\dim \Sigma <n$ then NO. Consider $\alpha:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\alpha(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$.
5. The map $h|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ is an embedding.

Observe $h(\Sigma)=h(\operatorname{int} \Sigma)\coprod h(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something here, since I don't see how 6 is true, but it seems false in dimension $1$, since $\Sigma$ is disconnected but you can arrange for $h$ to have connected image.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Sorry yes I was thinking of higher dimensions, and disregard $6$.

Comment: I guess yes, but not sure. Since $\Sigma = [0;1)\times S^{n-1}$ and $h\big|_{S^{n-1}\times[0;1/2]}$ is an embedding, it suffices to prove that in some neighbourhood of $h(S^{n-1}\times\{0\})$ there are no points of $h(S^{n-1}\times(1/2;1)).$ By Alexander duality $h(S^{n-1}\times\{0\})$ splits the space into two parts, one of which is already locally occupied by $h(S^{n-1}\times(0;1/2)).$ Since $h$ is injection and since $h(S^{n-1}\times(0;1))$ lies to the one side of $h(S^{n-1}\times\{0\})$, the claim follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is yes.** It suffices to show that $h$ restricted to each of the sets $1\leq |x|\leq 3/2$ and $3/2\leq |x|<2$ is an embedding, because the image of points near the boundary $|x|=2$ will be away from the image of
$1\leq |x|\leq 3/2$. Indeed, by the generalized Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem $1\leq |x|\leq 3/2$ and $3/2\leq |x|<2$ will be in different components of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(\{|x|=3/2\})$.

Thus the only problem is to verify that $h$ is an embedding near $|x|=2$. However, according to [The generalized Schoenflies theorem](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/Schoenflies.pdf) of Mazur and Brown the map $h$ restricted to $3/2\leq |x|<2$ extends to an embedding of $|x|<2$
and hence $h$ is an embedding of $3/2\leq |x|<2$.

**Here is a second (even more elementary) argument:**

According to Brouwer's invariance of domain theorem $h$ restricted to $1<|x|<2$ is an embedding.  It is also an embedding of $1\leq |x|\leq 3/2$ (by compactness of the domain).
Since the image of $|x|=1$ is at a positive distance to the image of  $3/2\leq |x|<2$ (by the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem as explained above), it follows that $h$ is an embedding of $1\leq |x|<2$.